# How to return error to dbus using qt-dbus?

Tags: qtdbus

I'm using qt-dbus to expose some API from my software.

I convert foo.xml with interface declaration to foo_adaptor.cpp and foo_adaptor.h holding  FooAdaptor class via qdbusxml2cpp, then I bind real Foo class to the FooAdaptor by calling new FooAdaptor(this) inside Foo's constructor.

So, it works: Foo metods are called, when I send message via dbus-send to my app.

For specific builds of my software I want to disable some methods.
I need somehow to inform the caller, that some method call actually unallowed and does nothing/have no meaning.
Is there any function to call/exception to throw to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Error responses can be sent by making your D-Bus object (the one registered with `QDBusConnection::registerObject()`, not the adaptor) inherit from `QDBusContext` and then using the `sendErrorReply()` method:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdbus/qdbuscontext.html

Comment: It should be noted this largely defeats the purpose of adaptors. The object being exported now knows about D-Bus.